# inline CLOSURE/Anonymous function inside string?

Tags: php, closures

I want to return a dynamic string inside variable . Is it possible somehow to achieve something like this:

```
$str =  'Hi  '. (function(){ return 'Jimmy'; }) ;
```

p.s. I need like what ask, not alternative solutions.

Comment: Almost every time I ask something on SO, the first comment is "WHY DO YOU WANT THAT". please, don't ask that, i am tired of justifying the reasons why I need that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to execute the closure inside the variable instance. You cannot have mixed data types, it is either a closure or a string.

**PHP 5 +** (Thanks to @[omerowitz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52895079/include-closure-function-inside-string#comment92703094_52895187) input)

```
$str = 'Hi  '. call_user_func( function(){ return 'Jimmy'; } ) ;
```

btw, Shorter version exists in **PHP 7+**

```
$str =  'Hi  '. (function() { return 'Jimmy'; }) ();
```

The above would output as:

> Hi Jimmy

2020 Update reviewing the question:

If you want to pass an argument, and for some reason you’re still using PHP 5.2 <, you can use

```
call_user_func_array(function($name) { return $name; }, [‘Jimmy’]);
```

Comment: Indeed, wrapping the function inside braces just means "do this first". For example, `$foo = new Foo(); $foo->doSomething();` could be shortened to `(new Foo())->doSomething();`. In this case, you're returning a closure from `(function() {})` so to execute it, you must add `()` at the end of the closure.

Comment: For PHP 5 or less you can use `call_user_func()` but nicely pointed out @omerowitz